# Transferring installed R packages to R on another computer

Tags: r, linux, package

I have R installed on one linux computer where there are number of packages installed. Now I am setting up R on another linux computer. Installing R is easy from their repository but I will have to install many packages using

```
install.packages("pkgname")
```

which will involve repeat downloading as well. Is there any way I can copy all the installed packages from first computer to the second one? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend against this approach.  Some of those packages will have been installed from source *which includes compile-time checks based on what is installed on "computer one"* and that will not necessarily be true on the other computer.

You have two basic choices

1. Use binary package (ie `r-cran-pkgname` for various packages).  These will work but a) not all of CRAN exists that way and b) they may lag the current release.
2. Install from source. Just run `saveRDS(installed.packages(), file="/tmp/pkgs.rds")` on the first computer and `pkgs <- readRDS("/tmp/pkgs.rds"); install.packages(rownames(pkgs))` on the second after transfering the file.